# Load Javascript When Clicking On External Link

Tags: javascript, onload

I want to have several links on a page. Let's call this page website.com/the-page-1.

When each of the unique links on this page are clicked, they open a new page on the site, let's call it /the-page-2/

When /the-page-2/ is opened, I want the javascript from /the-page-2/ to load based on the link that was clicked from /the-page-1/

So basically each link from /the-page-1/ makes a different script run on /the-page-2/

I've tried this on /the-page-1/, but it didn't work:

```
<a href="/the-page-2" target="_blank" onload="script('javascript:loadPlaylist(threekeysnaturalrelationship')">Link Text</a>
```

BTW I'm trying to load a playlist into JW player on /the-page-2.

Currently I have all the javascript properly loaded on /the-page-2 and I can get a specific to play using onclick, but ONLY when the onclick link is on /the-page-2/

I need it to work when it's clicked from /the-page-1/

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting some values into local storage, based on different links clicked, and then depending on that load different scripts. I believe it's worth looking into JS Session and Local Storage, hope it solves your issue.

You can easily set and get values paired with keyes.

localStorage.setItem("scriptId", "1");

// Access some stored data
localStorage.getItem("scriptId"));